# Unable to send emails with attachment using elastic email API in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email-attachments, email

I have used TCPDF to generate PDF, which is working fine.I'm trying to send email with PDF generated as attachment to the email. Emails are being sent without attachment. Please help in correcting the codes below to ensure attachment is also sent in the email.

payment.php

```
$attachment =  $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'D');
$attachment = base64_encode($attachment);

$attachmentlink = 'http://localhost/cfac/resources/invoices/example_001.pdf';

$inputdata['firstname']="abc";
$inputdata['ename']="Event Name";
$inputdata['tno']="tno:232423";
$inputdata['amount']="10000rs";
$inputdata['edetails']="EDetails";
$inputdata['startdate']="Start Date";
$inputdata['enddate']="End Date";
$template='xyz';

$emailid="xxx@gmail.com";
// email helper to send email
$this->load->helper ('email');

        $filename = "example_001.pdf";
        $file_name_with_full_path = base_url()."resources/inv/example_001.pdf";
        $filetype = "application/pdf";

        $attachmentFiles = array('http://localhost/cfac/resources/inv/example_001.pdf');


        send_email($emailid,$inputdata,$template, $attachmentFiles );
```

emailhelper.php

emailconfig deatils have been set with values in config file.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


if ( ! function_exists('send_email'))
{

function send_email($emailid,$inputdata,$template,$attachmentFiles )
{

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->config('emailcofnig');
    //$ci->email->attach( 'http://localhost/cfac/resources/inv/example_001.pdf');

    $emailconfig=$CI->config->item('elasticemail');

    $url=$emailconfig['url'];

    $filename = "example_001.pdf";
    $file_name_with_full_path = "http://localhost/cfac/resources/invoices/example_001.pdf";
    $filetype = "application/pdf";


    $email = array(
        'from' => $emailconfig['fromemailid'],
        'fromName' => $emailconfig['from'],
        'apikey' => $emailconfig['apikey'],
        'subject' => $emailconfig['defaultsubject'],
        'to' => $emailid,
        'isTransactional' => true,
        'template' => $templatename,
        'file_1' => new CurlFile($file_name_with_full_path, $filetype, $filename)
        );

        foreach($inputdata as $key => $value)
        {
            $email['merge_'.$key] = $value;
        }



    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($email)
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ return 0;}

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$ci = get_instance();
                $ci->load->library('email');
                $config['protocol'] =  $ci->config->item('protocol');
                $config['smtp_host'] = $ci->config->item('smtp_host');
                $config['smtp_port'] = $ci->config->item('smtp_port');
                $config['smtp_user'] = $ci->config->item('smtp_user');
                $config['smtp_pass'] = $ci->config->item('smtp_pass');
                $config['charset'] =  $ci->config->item('charset');
                $config['mailtype'] = $ci->config->item('mailtype');
                $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

                $ci->email->initialize($config);
                $ci->email->from("no-reply@nirbachon.net", $ci->config->item('smtp_user_display_name'));
                $ci->email->to($email);
                $ci->email->cc($cc);
                $ci->email->bcc($bcc);
                $ci->email->reply_to("no-reply@nirbachon.net", $ci->config->item('smtp_user_display_name'));
                $ci->email->subject($subject);
                if($attachment != null){
                  $ci->email->attach($attachment);
                }
                $ci->email->message($email_body);
                $ci->email->send();
```